# How to extract content from HTML strings

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract contents from DIV tag. I am using scrapy to scrap some site but the problem is Same DIV tag has two type of contents:

```
["<div class=\"price\">\n                <s>Rs.330</s> <b>Rs.297</b>\n                              </div>"]
```

And

```
["<div class=\"price\">\n                Rs.330              \n</div>"]
```

How do I extract contents from this tag?

Comment: Scrapy uses xpaths for the scrapping try `//div[contains(@class,'price')]/s/@text`

Comment: Yes i tried that but as same DIV has two type of contents for different products....thing is some time DIV has price or some time DIV has <s> <b> with items so how do i differentiate between them....that's why i was looking for something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

html = "<div class=\"price\">\n                <s>Rs.330</s> <b>Rs.297</b>\n                              </div>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="xml")
s = soup.div.s.text # u'Rs.330'
b = soup.div.b.text # u'Rs.297'
```